# Getting assertion error for unit test

Tags: hardhat, unittesting, test

Im getting the assertion error
[image]

the test

```js
it("return false if enough time hasnt passed", async function(){
                await expect(raffle.enterRaffle({value: raffleEntranceFee}))
                await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [interval.toNumber() - 1])
                await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine",params: []})
                const {upkeepNeeded} = await raffle.callStatic.checkUpkeep([])
                assert.equal(upkeepNeeded, false)
            })
```

and also my test case is passing if I remove the line  `await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine",params: []})`
only getting error if the line is present

https://github.com/yash-2138/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery

Answer (score 0):

I had the same assertion error.
When I checked the main `Raffle.sol` contract, I saw that I didn't set the `s_lastTimeStamp` variable in the constructor. So make sure you set the `s_lastTimeStamp` variable in the constructor like this:
[image: setting s_lastTimeStamp in constructor]